# Why do we put a 'where' after defining data types in Agda?

Tags: agda, agda-mode

Suppose I wish to define Bool as a type, I would write:

> data Bool : Type where

I don't quite understand why I must keep 'where' at the end, what purpose does it play in the Syntax? Why was the above preferred over say:

> data Bool : Type

Was this arbitrary or is there some deep logic underlying?

By the way, I am a total noob at programming, so please explain using most simple words.

Comment: What you are asking is the *concrete syntax*. Concrete syntax is always arbitrary. So apart from looking good and feeling good there is essentially no reason something is this way or that.

Comment: To be idiomatic. It's good to have a keyword that separates the type and the clause defining the judgements.

Answer (score 3):

With the `where` keyword, we can write the following:

```
data Bool : Set where true false : Bool
```

Without the `where` keyword, this would be

```
data Bool : Set true false : Bool
```

but this would be ambiguous: `true` could be defined to be an element of type `Level`, in which case this would be defining a datatype at sort `Set true` with a single constructor `false`.